# Cannot print but can scan with Canon MX860 connected via USB to Linux Mint

Tags: printing, linux-mint

I can open up Simple Scan and click 'scan' and the scanner fires right up. I can open up Printers under Preferences and see the printer there.

When I try to print a document, whether it's a pdf or a text file or even a test page from the Printers interface, the number of active jobs cycles up to 1 and back to 0 - accompanied by a 'Printing completed' notification - but the printer itself does nothing.

Comment: *"or even a test page from the Printers interface..."*  -- Is this on the PC?  Can you initiate a print test page or status page from the front panel?

Comment: That's on the PC. I can print a test page from the printer front panel.

Comment: Check the `Device URI` setting in the printer's properties.  If this is a network printer, then try alternate protocols.  One time my network printer stopped working after some system updates, and I had to reconfigure the Device URI.